# NextAuth Google login directly from the homepage without redirecting to the default sign-in page or custom sign-in page in NextJs

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth for my NextJS application. When using NextAuth, it redirects to its own sign-in page when signing in or we can add our own custom sign-in page but what I want to do is sign-in without redirecting it to the sign-in page directly from the homepage login button. Any ideas on how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you can do something like this ...

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/client"

export default () => (
  <button onClick={() => signIn("google")}>Sign in with Google</button>
)
```

So you can use pass any OAuth provider that are compatible with NextAuth to signIn and it will use that provider by default instead of redirecting you to a page.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to authenticate with google without redirect? so that the OAuth dialog opens in an iframe instead of a new page? (so I won't lose all the client state)

Answer (score 4):

Next auth 4 this is bit different. Need to import from **next-auth/react**,

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"

export default () => (
  <button onClick={() => signIn('google')}>Sign in with Google</button>
)
```